# Meta-regression for continuous data - effect size or otherwise?

Tags: regression, meta-analysis, weighted-regression, meta-regression

I'm trying to parse the output of multiple studies to quantify how age impacts the prevalence of HPV in Europe. Thanks to an excellent suggestion in a [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/575284/combining-data-from-multiple-studies-best-approach?), it has been suggested that meta-regression of the continuous data from my 16 included studies might be the way to go. The approximately linear results from these 16 studies (all with varying number of participants) are depicted below*.

[image]

I think I should apply a hierarchical random effects model between studies to get a global estimate of the regression co-efficient and variable, but in all the examples I've seen of meta-regression so far, authors essentially compare apply meta-regression by looking at effect size and variance between studies rather than the data itself. ***Firstly, is there a meta-regression method to compare such data without resorting to effect sizes from regression lines?*** If so, any example or guidance would be useful! Presuming there is not, should I

(a) Derive effect size / variance from regression co-efficient of each study, then perform a meta-regression on effect size?

(b) Just weigh the raw data by sample size or similar and perform a regression using weighed least squares fitting, which produces the central line shown in the figure?

Open to suggestion, apologies for the novice question!

Comment: You could regard (transformed) prevalence as response and age as _dose_ and search in your favourite software for meta-analysis of dose-response data. There is at least one R package for this.